# How to update fields and refresh single row in ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview

Hi I have say 100+ list items in the server and getting list items using pagination concept(Every time I am getting 10 list items at a time). Till then I am fine with my coding.

I have one class named `A` and has `listView`;

and my POJO is :

```
   public class StreamBean{
      private String description;
      private String thumbnailUrl;

      public String getDescription() {
            return mDescription;
        }

     public void setDescription(String mDescription) {
           this.mDescription = mDescription;
        }
     public String getThumbnailUrl() {
            return thumbnailUrl;
        }

    public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
            this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
       }
    }
```

I am getting 10 items in the first service call and storing in `List<StreamBean>` and passing to adapter and showing the results.Till Now I am clear.

Now, I am updating my description in the new **class B** and Getting back when it is finished editing(In Editing class I am calling service call).

In `Class A` I am showing updated description using `position` as

```
View v = gridView.getChildAt(position-gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition());

    if(v==null){
        return;
    }

    ImageView assetThumbnail = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.asset_thumbnail);
    TextView description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_description);

    if (streamBean.getImageBean() != null
            && !TextUtils.isEmpty(streamBean.getImageBean()
                    .getThumbnailUrl())){
        Glide.with(this)
        .load(streamBean.getImageBean()
                .getThumbnailUrl())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(assetThumbnail);
    }

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(streamBean.getDescription())){
        description.setText(streamBean.getDescription());
    }
```

Till Now I am fine with my coding.

Now my problems are that:

`1)` When I am doing editing operation for the same list item, I am getting previous description. How can I get the updated description?

`2)` When I am getting list using pagination, how can I refresh the listItem and place updated StreamBean into existing one.

May be I am wrong with understanding or questions. Please help me with your answers. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If i got your problem. try to change content of StreamBean object in list. and call notifyDataSetChanged method of adapter.

Comment: Hi #Hradesh Kumar. Thanks for your reply. But unfortunately your answer is not working with my requirement.